# Why are multiples of 11 palindromes?

Tags: palindrome

One thing I noticed is that for any integer $-10<a<10$, $11a$ is always a palindrome. I'm assuming this is because 11 is the first row of Pascal's triangle. For that same reason, for any nonnegative integer $n<5$, $(11a)^n$ is a palindrome.

Is there a proof for this? Is there a proper formula that proves that multiples of 11 are palindromes?

Comment: $11a$ is not always a palindrome. e.g. $11 \cdot 10 = 110$

Comment: But that's not true: put $a=15$, e.g.  Then $11\cdot 15 = 165$

Comment: $\;11\cdot132=1452\;$ ...doesn't look too palindromic to me...

Comment: You're correct - let me update this.

Comment: It is true, however, that all palindromes with an even number of digits are divisible by $11$.

Comment: For which multiples?  Aside from $1$ to $9$, for which integer $n$ is $11n$ a palindrome?

Comment: @Dr.MV $11\cdot 11$ is a palindrome.  As is $11^3$ and $11^4$.

Comment: @DWiggles Yes, I know.  My point was to find all of them.

Comment: @Dr.MV Like I said in the question - (11a)^n for -10<a<10 and -1<n<5.

Comment: @MarcusStuhr 121 doesn't contain an even number of digits. Neither does 14641.

Comment: @drmv Is -121 not a palindrome?

Comment: @DonielF Sometimes a palindrome with an odd number of digits can be divisible by $11$, but not all of them. My claim was that all palindromes with an even length are divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $11 = 10 + 1$, the binomial theorem gives
$$
11^{n} = (10 + 1)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 10^{n - k}.
$$
If $0 \leq n < 5$, then $\binom{n}{k} < 10$, i.e., is represented base $10$ by a single digit. Concretely,
\begin{align*}
  11^{2} &= 121, \\
  11^{3} &= 1331, \\
  11^{4} &= 14641, \\
  11^{5} &= 161051.
\end{align*}
(At the fifth power, there's carrying from $\binom{5}{2} = \binom{5}{3} = 10$.)

The question about $11a$ is similar but trivial: If $0 < a < 10$ is a single digit base $10$, then $11a = 10a + a$ has decimal representation $aa$.

It's not true that $(11a)^{n}$ is a palindrome, e.g., $22^{5} = 5153632$.